# Для чего используется и как работает метод notifyDataSetChanged()?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Писал программу по книге "Android программирование для профессионалов". Там, для того, чтобы обновить данные в списке, использовался метод `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                         Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   ... 
}
@Override public void onResume() { 
   super.onResume(); 
   updateUI();
 }
private void updateUI() { 
   CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()); 
   List<Crime> crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();  
  if (mAdapter == null) {   
     mAdapter = new CrimeAdapter(crimes); 
     mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
   } else {   
     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
 }
```

Но когда я убирал метод `notifyDataSetChanged()` и приводил код `updateUI()` к виду:

```
    private void updateUI() { 
       CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()); 
       List<Crime> crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();   
         mAdapter = new CrimeAdapter(crimes); 
         mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
}
```

Всё работало точно также. Всё, что я добавлял в другую активность, добавлялось в список, также, как и с использованием `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: `Для ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged работает только если вы используете его методы add(), insert(), remove(), and clear()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example

Comment: Метод говорит адаптеру что данные изменились и он должен обновить их отображение на экране. Во втором варианте вы каждый раз создаёте новый адаптер и присваиваете его ресайклеру - это тоже приводит к обновлению экрана, но такой вариант не оптимален - все вью-элементы создаются заново, тогда как в первом варианте только меняется контент.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод `notifyDataSetChanged()` указывает адаптеру, что полученные ранее данные изменились и следует перерисовать список на экране.

Из за изменений кода ничего не поменялось только визуально, программно же все стало намного печальнее.

В коде из книги проверяется, создан ли адаптер для списка и если не создан, то создается новый, а если создан, то обновляются данные уже имеющегося адаптера. Таким образом мы имеем только один объект, который работает все время отображения списка.

В вашем случае каждый раз создаётся новый адаптер, независимо от того, есть уже точно такой же или нет. Это крайне не оптимальное решение, так как объекты адаптера и содержимого списка будут плодиться с частотой обновления этого списка, заполнять собой память и нагружать сборщик мусора. После каждого такого обновления созданный до этого адаптер будет просто выкинут и останется бесполезным грузом занимать память, взамен его создаётся новый и так каждый раз при очередном обновлении списка.

p.s: во многом  благодаря таким решениям и вот этим вот "ничего же не изменилось" андроид и имеет репутацию тормозной и глючной системы

Comment: Премного благодарен!